# Is there a way for a developer to access BIA sensor API on Samsung Watch 4?

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

So I want to access the BIA sensor on Samsung Watch4 ([Measure your body composition with the Galaxy Watch4 series](https://www.samsung.com/levant/support/mobile-devices/measure-your-body-composition-with-the-galaxy-watch4-series/)), but can't really seem to find a way to do it. I wanted to know that:

Is it necessary to apply to Partner App Program to get access to body composition data ([Partner App Program](https://developer.samsung.com/health/platform/overview.html))? Or is there some other way?